# What are "Avatar Items" in Xbox Store?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-series-x-series-s

What are "Avatar Items" in Xbox Store?

[Example](https://www.xbox.com/en-us/Search?q=pinball) search result in Xbox Store.

In forums they call profiles pictures avatars. But when I look at the cost of that, I think it's more than just a picture.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an xbox avatar using the Xbox Avatar Editor app

To create a new avatar

1. Press the Xbox button to open the guide.
2. Select My games & apps > See all
3. Go to Apps and select the Xbox Avatar Editor app.
4. Select an avatar, and then customize it however you like.

You can then use this avatar to create your gamerpic for your xbox profile.

In other words, this is more than just a profile picture. It's an interactive model person that you can create as you see fit. You can choose skin color, hair styles, eye color, clothing, accessories and more. It used to play a larger part of the xbox ecosystem then it currently does.

Comment: I actually thought Avatars were phased out completely, but I guess they are just obscurely hidden away.  The Xbox 360 era (after they updated from the "Blades" dashboard to the "New Xbox Experience" dashboard) was when they introduced Avatars I believe.  Pretty sure once the Xbox One was released, they weren't really present anymore, and that probably contributed to their decline.

Comment: @TimmyJim I really enjoy(ed) them. Wish they weren't so difficult to find.